# Canned air and Liquid Submersion Indicator (LSI) Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, repair, damage

I think this is more a chemistry stack exchange question but I believe being related to a computer it isn't well received there.

Canned air spray is used to clean dusty internal or external components. Sometimes it has vapor or liquid that comes out in pressure.

I wonder if it is able to trigger Liquid Submersion Indicator (LSI) or Liquid Contact Indicator (LCI) present on MacBooks motherboard.

This indicators turn red when in contact with (water?)

Wiki always refer to water so i'm not sure.

Apple recommends using canned air spray for some macbook keyboards[1] but i guess the layers of keyboard are more resistant to liquid contact.

[1] https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205662

Comment: I've used canned-air on iPhones for quite a while with nary an issue. I find that shaking the can and firing off a brief burst **before** you use it on the phone and then only *very brief bursts* will minimize the vapor you see. I do believe I heard that the vapor you see is water vapor but it is condensing out of the air, so brief bursts will minimize the water vapor.

Comment: I used to clean label printers and a music CD distributor warehouse refused to allow canned air to clean the printers because the workers would hold the cans upside down and freeze insects in mid-flight.  They thought it was great fun.  We ended up installing an air compressor with a hose short enough to just reach the printers.  I seriously doubt even an upside down can spraying very cold propellant would trigger the chemical sensors.  There is a hack to freeze RAM chips long enough to yank them and reseat in another system to read the contents.